# What is “pivot table” in eloquent-relationships?

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

Reading Laravel 6 eloquent-relationships docs at https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one
I did not catch what is “pivot table” and which is practical use of it working with db in laravel ?

Thanks!

Comment: it is an intermediate Table, when you using many-to-many relationship.

Comment: This is the section that explains pivot tables: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think you have two tables like `users`, and `roles` if you want to make a relationship between them then you need to declare `Many To Many` relationships because the single role have many users and single users have many roles. for defining `Many To Many` relationships between them you need to create `role_user` table, here `role_user` table means `pivot table`.

for more information please read this [Many To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationships from laravel documentation